# Tomcat ldap url authentication

Tags: tomcat, ldap

How to setup tomcat ldap url authentication?

Answer (score 2):

LDAP authentication in Tomcat can be configured using a [JNDIRealm](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/realm-howto.html#JNDIRealm).